# Сложный запрос с арифметическими вычислениями

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть три таблицы: Abonent, Meter, Values

```
Abonent:  
UUID (uuid) | Name (string)  
0001        | IVAN  
0002        | PETR

Meter:  
UUID (uuid) | METER_SN (string)  
0001        | 101  
0001        | 102  
0002        | 201  
0002        | 202  
0002        | 203

Values:  
METER_SN (string) | Date (date) | Values (integer)  
101               | 01.01.2018  | 10  
101               | 02.01.2018  | 11  
101               | 10.01.2018  | 12  
101               | 31.01.2018  | 19  
102               | 01.01.2018  | 21  
102               | 02.01.2018  | 22  
102               | 10.01.2018  | 23  
102               | 31.01.2018  | 29  
...  
203               | 01.01.2018  | 236  
203               | 31.01.2018  | 239
```

Мне нужно одним запросом получить таблицу вида:

```
NAME | METER_SN | DIFFERENCE_VALUE  
IVAN | 101      | 9  
IVAN | 102      | 8  
...  
PETR | 203      | 3
```

Где DIFFERENCE_VALUE разница между значением на последний день месяца и первый день месяца

```
SELECT Abonent.name AS Name, 
       Meter.meter_sn AS SerNum, 
       (SELECT values 
        FROM   Values 
        WHERE  Date <= '31.01.2018' ORDER BY Date DESC) 
        - 
       (SELECT values 
        FROM   Values 
        WHERE  Date >= '01.01.2018' ORDER BY Date ASC ) AS difference_value 
FROM   Abonent 
INNER  JOIN Meter 
ON     Abonent.UUID = Meter.UUID 
INNER  JOIN Values 
ON     Meter.Meter_sn = Values.Meter_sn 
WHERE  UUID IN ( '0001', '0002' )
```

Comment: А как вы пробовали и что у вас не получилось?

Comment: Viktorov, SELECT Abonent.name AS Name, Meter.meter_sn AS SerNum, ( SELECT values FROM Values WHERE  Date >= '31.01.2018' ORDER BY Date DESC) -  ( SELECT values FROM Values WHERE  Date <= '01.01.2018'   ORDER BY Date ASC)  AS difference_value FROM Abonent INNER JOIN Meter ON Abonent.UUID = Meter.UUID INNER JOIN ValuesON Meter.Meter_sn = Values.Meter_sn WHERE UUID IN ( '0001', '0002' )

Comment: Victorov, В результате запроса получается, что разница одинаковая. Пример немного некорректен тем, что разница везде одинаковая получается 9.

Comment: Я понимаю, что результат  ( SELECT values FROM Values WHERE Date >= '31.01.2018' ORDER BY Date DESC) - ( SELECT values FROM Values WHERE Date <= '01.01.2018' ORDER BY Date ASC)  будет всегда одним числом, но как сделать иначе?

Comment: Я пытаюсь понять, какой результат вы хотите, и не понимаю. Возможно получится как словами более подробно описать?

Comment: Хочется увидеть что-то в духе "Для каждого абонента надо посчитать разницу чего то там, связи в таблицах такие то"

Comment: Мне нужно вывести имя, номер счетчика и показания счетчика за месяц. Показания за месяц вычисляются путем разницы между показаниями на конец месяца и на начало месяца. Но бывает так, что показания на 1 число отсутствуют, поэтому берутся показания >= 01.01.2018, показания на 31 аналогично могут отсутствовать, поэтому берем <= 31.01.2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так. Запрос находит разницу между первым и последним измерением в течении месяца. Если измерение было только одно, то в результат вернется "-1".

```
select name,
       meter_sn,
       diff 
from (       
      select name, 
             meter_sn, 
             val, 
             rn1, 
             rn2,
             COALESCE(lag(val) over(partition by name, meter_sn order by rn2) - val, -1) as diff -- если тут получается null, то было только 1 измерение. Тогда вернем -1                 l
      from  (
              select a.name, m.meter_sn, v.val,               
                     row_number() over(partition by a.name, m.meter_sn order by v."Date") as rn1, 
                     row_number() over(partition by a.name, m.meter_sn order by v."Date" desc) as rn2
              from   abonent a
              left   join Meter m
              on     a.uuid = m.uuid
              left   join val v
              on     m.meter_sn = v.meter_sn       
              where  v."Date" between  to_date('01.01.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy') and to_date('31.01.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy')  -- возьмем данные только за нужный месяц. Если вдруг время с секундами, то возможно это стоит учеть отдельно.      
             ) as t
      where  rn1 = 1 -- это первое измерение в месяце
      or     rn2 = 1 -- это последнее изменение в месяце
      ) as t2
where rn1 = 1
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fb887/26

Объяснение работы:

Пусть есть набор данных:

```
Abonent
---------------------------    
UUID (uuid) | Name (string)  
0001        | IVAN  


Meter
--------------------------------    
UUID (uuid) | METER_SN (string)  
0001        | 101  
0001        | 102  

Values
--------------------------------------------------
METER_SN (string) | Date (date) | Values (integer)  
101               | 01.01.2018  | 10  
101               | 02.01.2018  | 11  
101               | 10.01.2018  | 12  
101               | 31.01.2018  | 19
```

На первом шаге выберем все данные за нужный месяц (`where  v."Date" between  to_date('01.01.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy') and to_date('31.01.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy')`)  и пронумеруем их с сортировкой дате в прямом(`rn`) и обратном(`rn2`) порядке.
Получим такой результат:

```
Name|Meter_SN|Date         |Values|rn1|rn2
------------------------------------------
IVAN|101     | 01.01.2018  | 10   | 1 | 4
IVAN|101     | 02.01.2018  | 11   | 2 | 3
IVAN|101     | 10.01.2018  | 12   | 3 | 2
IVAN|101     | 31.01.2018  | 19   | 4 | 1
```

Из этого набора заберем только первую и последнюю строку по дате(`where  rn1 = 1 or rn2 = 1`), получим:

```
Name|Meter_SN|Date         |Values|rn1|rn2
------------------------------------------
IVAN|101     | 01.01.2018  | 10   | 1 | 4
IVAN|101     | 31.01.2018  | 19   | 4 | 1
```

Теперь все нужные нам данные есть. Но для вычитания надо, чтобы они были в одной строке. Для этого используется функция `lag(val) over(partition by name, meter_sn order by rn2)`. Подробнее про оконные функции [оконные функции](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/10/functions-window)
Если в кратце, то эта функция вернет предыдущую строку с учетом сортировки и группировки. Тогда  набор данных получится такой:

```
Name|Meter_SN|Date         |Values|rn1|rn2| lag ...
----------------------------------------------------   
IVAN|101     | 01.01.2018  | 10   | 1 | 4 | 19
IVAN|101     | 31.01.2018  | 19   | 4 | 1 | null
```

Остается только вычесть нужные значения друг из друга(`COALESCE(lag(val) over(partition by name, meter_sn order by rn2) - val, -1) as diff`) и взять только нужную строку (`where rn1 = 1`).
`COALESCE` используется для того, чтобы заменить `Null` значения на '-1' для случаев, когда было только одно измерение. В таком случае функция `lag` не найдет значение из окна и вернет значение по умолчанию(`Null`).

Comment: Спасибо, да действительно работает. Но вы не могли бы объяснить немного поподробнее? Дело в том, что как вы наверное уже поняли этот пример упрощенный,а моя реальная задача несколько сложнее и мне важно понять идею.

Comment: @ЕвгенийДружинин постарался максимально подробно описать(Дополнил ответ). Как еще подробнее объяснить не знаю. Если что-то все еще не понятно, задавайте конкретные вопросы

Comment: Подскажите, а как быть в том случае, если необходимо взять данные за не с 01.01.2018, а последнюю запись(по времени) с 31.12.2017?  Например у нас данные на 31.12.2017 8:00, 31.12.2017 9:00 и 31.12.2017 23:59. Как сделать так, чтобы в строке                                                                                           
where  v."Date" between  to_date('01.01.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy') and to_date('31.01.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy') это учесть?

Comment: в `to_date` указать время и маску с часами. Наверное что-то  в духе `to_date('31.12.2017 08:00:00','DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS')`. Погуглите, как в постгре правильно маски форматов даты выглядят, я сейчас наугад отчасти написал

Comment: А как быть когда знаю только дату, но не знаю время. И мне нужно взять именно последнюю запись на 31.12.2017 по времени? функции row_number() over(partition by a.name, m.meter_sn order by v."Date") as rn1, дата отсортируется  ASC и возьмется первая запись на 31.12.2017, а мне нужно как нибудь получить последнюю запись на эту дату.

Comment: Наверное ваш запрос вы вызываете из приложения какого то, тогда в between вы передаете дату просто параметром с типом `date` и все приседания с приведением типов вам не нужны. 
Rn1 - это первая дата. Rn2 - последняя. Не зависимо от минут и секунд, сортировка будет правильная

Comment: Да, дату я действительно вставляю в запрос из приложения. Но я не знаю время последней записи. Я могу оперировать только двумя датами например 31.12.2017 и 31.01.2018. Но помимо дат есть ещё и время, а его я не знаю и мне нужно получить разницу значений между последним значением по времени на дату 31.01.2018 и 31.12.2017

Comment: Напишите время 24:59:59

Comment: имеете ввиду 23.59.59? Но тогда он возьмет первую запись с датой 01.01.2018 и каким то временем, а мне нужна последняя запись на 31.12.2017

Comment: Действительно,31.12.2017 23:59:59.  С такой датой он никак не зацепит запись за 01.01.2018. Просто попробуйте

Comment: @Victorov Действительно, не берет запись за 01.01.2018, но почему то берет запись до 31.12.2017 23:59:59, например на 31.12.2017 15:15:15 Не понятно почему так происходит? Я думал, что BETWEEN это аналог  условия >= Или я что то не так понимаю?

Comment: Не ту я функцию использовал, нужно использовать to_timestamp()

Comment: Я не понял, в чем проблема. `31.12.2017 15:15:15` < `31.12.2017 23:59:59`. По моему все так и должно работать. Between - это находится между или равен

Comment: Все нормально, я не ту функцию использовал. Когда помимо даты есть еще  и время, то нужно использовать функцию to_timestamp()