# Как применить оконную функцию lag() в конструкции WHERE

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблицы и значения в вопросе [Сложный запрос с арифметическими вычислениями](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/811531/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8/811616?noredirect=1#comment1289944_811616)

```
    select name,
       meter_sn,
       diff 
from (       
      select name, 
             meter_sn, 
             val, 
             rn1, 
             rn2,
             COALESCE(lag(val) over(partition by name, meter_sn order by rn2) - val, -1) as diff -- если тут получается null, то было только 1 измерение. Тогда вернем -1                 l
      from  (
              select a.name, m.meter_sn, v.val,               
                     row_number() over(partition by a.name, m.meter_sn order by v."Date") as rn1, 
                     row_number() over(partition by a.name, m.meter_sn order by v."Date" desc) as rn2
              from   abonent a
              left   join Meter m
              on     a.uuid = m.uuid
              left   join val v
              on     m.meter_sn = v.meter_sn       
              where  v."Date" between  lag(to_date('01.01.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy')) and to_date('31.01.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy')  -- возьмем данные только за нужный месяц. Если вдруг время с секундами, то возможно это стоит учеть отдельно.      
             ) as t
      where  rn1 = 1 -- это первое измерение в месяце
      or     rn2 = 1 -- это последнее изменение в месяце
      ) as t2
where rn1 = 1
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fb887/29

при попытке выполнить этот запрос выдается ошибка: Оконные функции нельзя применять в конструкции WHERE.
Каким образом мне можно обойти эту ошибку, чтобы получить самую последнюю запись с датой 31.12.2017?

Comment: Перемести этот подзапрос в секцию `WITH`, поместив LAG()-и в выходной набор. А в запросе уже выполни фильтрацию. Делов-то...

Comment: @Akina Честно говоря никогда WITH не использовал. в Каком месте запроса нужно применять эту конструкцию?

Comment: Ну что-нибудь вроде http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fb887/31 ... я там для исправления синтаксического ляпа отфонарный OVER ещё добавил (у тебя в этом WHERE же LAG без OVER-a)... ну и в основном запросе ещё один подзапрос в итоге схлопнется.

Comment: @Akina Добавил в схему строку                                                       insert into val values('101', to_date('31.12.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 9);                       Но результата запроса нет. Подскажите, что я делаю неправильно?